# Open android settings page SCROLLED DOWN to a specific entry

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

I'm trying to make a part of my android app go directly to the USB debugging toggle in the settings
I've gotten it to open the Developer options page so far, using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

However, I've seen some apps (can't recall specific ones) that open a settings page and scroll down to a certain entry.
How can I do the same action, so that I can open the Developer options page *scrolled down* to the USB-debugging toggle?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't :-(

Comment: Thanks, @DavidWasser. After a couple days of research + trying to hack it in, I've decided it isn't possible.

Comment: There's an app called Power Shade that does the exact same thing. Unfortunately there isn't any documentation on this matter. Any leads?

Comment: @Royz it's been a few years since I tried this, so I don't fully recall specifics. I did end up finding a way to do this with Tasker separately, so I decided to skip adding this directly into my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple days of research + trying to hack it in, I've concluded that this isn't possible. My app would lose all control the second I call an activity. And there's no possible parameters I can send to the native settings app to launch scrolled down.